# how to link Fortran with Abaqus CAE 6.14 in Redhat linux terminal?

Tags: linux, fortran, redhat, abaqus

Does anyone know how to link Fortran with Abaqus CAE 6.14 in Redhat linux terminal?

If you could please tell me the steps elaborately, that would be great. I understand I need the Fortran compiler (ifort or gcc; I believe I have access to both!). I also already have Abaqus cae 6.14. I think there is an environment variable file involved in the process, but I don't know anything about this file or where to even locate it or what to do with it!

Please, if someone can tell me this step-by-step what to type in the terminal, that would be great! I really am an amateur in this!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something? Have you read some documentation? What do you mean by *"link Fortran with Abaqus"*? Do you have some code you need to compile? Which code?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start?

Comment: I know that I have to load the fortran compiler, which I can probabaly figure out! But after that, I wouldn't know what to type!

Comment: But to load for what? Why you want to load the compiler? Do you want to compile something? What exactly?

Comment: The usual reason for using a Fortran compiler along with Abaqus would be to incorporate a user written function, such as user material.  Abaqus provides far more documentation on this subject than could be covered on stackoverflow, including recommended compiler versions.

Comment: I will eventually write a fortran subroutine file (UMAT and if required USDFLD) and will run a job with Abaqus cae 6.14. But I will have to do this linking via linux terminal because that's where the Abaqus access is. Since I have academic licensing, I don't have explicit support from the experts in Abaqus, and there is no hint for the connection of fortran and Abaqus in linux os anywhere in the abaqus documentation (for windows there is!). I didn't find anything! I am very new to all of this! I wouldn't know where to start!

Comment: The manual is the first place you should start. It answers all of this. A certain level of prerequisite knowledge may be expected when you begin working with subroutines, but if you read thru it you should be able to figure out how to run an analysis, at minimum. Be resourceful, inquisitive, and determined. Keep notes. I started in the same situation you are in, and yes, it's a slog at times but not difficult if you apply yourself. And finally, remember that SO can be useful, but come here with specific tasks or problems instead of requesting a full-on tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Abaqus CAE seems to have problems finding the alias `ifort` (which should be automatically set up) when you install the intel fortran compiler. In order to check your installation of the fortran compiler, type in a terminal

```
$ ifort -v
```

The output should look like:

```
ifort version 16.0.2
```

If you have the fortran compiler, then you can just find its path by typing

```
whereis ifort
```

And you get something like (depending on your installation)

```
ifort: /opt/intel/bin/ifort /opt/intel/cpp-composer/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin/intel64/ifort
```

Knwoing that, you can go in the install directory of Abaqus (*e.g.* `/opt/abaqus`) and edit the `abaqus_v6.env` file which is located under

```
$(ABQ_INSTALL_DIR)/6.14-1/SMA/site
```

There you have to change

```
fortCmd = "ifort"
```

to what you got from the `whereis` command. In my case to

```
fortCmd = "/opt/intel/bin/ifort"
```

You should now be able to compile user subroutines from Abaqus CAE